# Python pandas - compare values

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Input and Expected Output]

1. How to copy value from for `NaN` from next row and add a flag as '(copy)'?
   done -

```
df = (df.bfill() + df.fillna(' (copy)').where(df.isna())).fillna(df)
```

2. How to compare the `row 2` & `row 3` values with that of row 1 and add a `string` as '(not same)' if the values are not same and get expected output??

Comment: Include data which can be copy-pasted, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the masks in variables so you can use them later:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[np.NaN,"Cat","Cheese"],
                   "col2":["Dog","Cheese","Dog"],
                   "col3":[np.NaN,"Cat","Dog"]})

copy_mask = df.isnull()

df = df.bfill()

same_mask = df!=df.iloc[0]

df[same_mask]+=" (Not same)"
df[copy_mask]+=" (Copy)"

print (df)

                col1               col2            col3
0         Cat (Copy)                Dog      Cat (Copy)
1                Cat  Cheese (Not same)             Cat
2  Cheese (Not same)                Dog  Dog (Not same)
```